# How to display an image stored as a page resource when it's an element of an array of objects?

Tags: go, hugo

Images in my front matter are stored like this:

```
images:
  - image: image_1.jpg
    caption: "image 1 caption"
  - image: image_2.jpg
    caption: "image 2 caption"
```

I want to display just the first one, so I use the following:

```
{{ $image := .Resources.GetMatch (printf "**%s" (index .Params.images 0).image) }}
```

Oddly, this only works if I add the `.image` part while my local hugo server is running. As soon as I stop and start it again, the site fails to rebuild with the following error:

```
... execute of template failed: template: partials/content/figure.html:7:70: executing "partials/content/figure.html" at <0>: can't evaluate field image in type string
```

I just want to be able to access `images[0].image`. How can I make this work?

Comment: A few clarifications so I can understand your code? Why are you using .GetMatch, and why printf? What problem are those for? Where are your images stores? How are you using that partial? What is the context?
{{ (resources.Get .imagepath).Permalink }} Should return the permalink just fine... Depends on context.

Comment: @Rogelio, Images are stored in leaf bundles. I don't have good answers for the other questions... I'm relatively new to Hugo and was trying to modify as little as possible from the theme/template I'm using, [Doks](https://getdoks.org/), which I assume has good reason for using .GetMatch and printf, since its developer seems to otherwise know what he's doing. Anyway, I've answered the question with a solution that worked well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had some other content types in which `images` in front matter were still simple arrays, rather than arrays of objects. This was causing my build error. To solve the problem, I used the following, as was recommended [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-display-an-image-stored-as-a-page-resource-when-its-an-element-of-an-array-of-objects/42873/8):

```
{{ $image := "" }}
{{ if reflect.IsMap (index .Params.images 0) }}
  {{ $image = .Resources.GetMatch (printf "**%s" (index .Params.images 0).image) }}
{{ else }}
  {{ $image = .Resources.GetMatch (printf "**%s" (index .Params.images 0)) }}
{{ end }}
```